# mp2 format files not playing iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I want to play some files which are in MP2 format in my iPhone app. The problem is that they play in few devices and do not in some other devices. I am not able to draw a pattern when they are working/not-working.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that they play on all iOS devices you should better convert the files to .mp4 and h.264. The problem with your mp2 files is probably the codec and not the file type. Thats why some of them play and some not.